# crontab doesn't see the $1 parameter by shell command

Tags: bash

I've written a small bash script that adds a crontab which runs another bash script every minute with a parameter which is set when running the first script.

so, this is the `main.sh` which you run like `./main.sh parameter1` and it adds a crontab like this;

```
function cronjobs {
  if ! crontab -l | grep "~/runthis.sh"; then
    (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * ~/runthis.sh $1") | crontab -
  fi
}
```

however, when I check the `crontab -e` seems like it doesn't have the `parameter1` and only this part getting added; `* * * * * ~/runthis.sh`.

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you pass the parameter `$1` to the function `cronjobs` in the script `main.sh`?

I tested your code, and it works.

File `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
function cronjobs {
  if ! crontab -l | grep "~/runthis.sh"; then
    (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * ~/runthis.sh $1") | crontab -
  fi
}

cronjobs "$1"
#        ^^^^ here
```

Run

```
./main.sh foobar
```

You will see a line in `crontab -l`

```
* * * * * ~/runthis.sh foobar
```

Update:

In bash scripts, we should use double quotes for variables unless we have special reasons.

Current script, if we run `./main.sh "foo bar"`

We will get

```
* * * * * ~/runthis.sh foo bar
```

It means that script `~/runthis.sh` will get two parameters `foo` and `bar`, not the one `foo bar`.

If the last line is `cronjobs $1`, run `./main.sh "foo bar"`

In `crontab -l`, We will get:

```
* * * * * ~/runthis.sh foo
```

Update script `main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
function cronjobs {
  if ! crontab -l | grep "~/runthis.sh"; then
    (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * ~/runthis.sh \"$1\"") | crontab -
  fi                                         #  ^^^^^^^ double quotes
}

cronjobs "$1"
#        ^^^^ here
```

Run

```
./main.sh "foo bar"
```

Will get

```
* * * * * ~/runthis.sh "foo bar"
```

Update:

If we want to add jobs with different parameters

`main.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
function cronjobs {
  if ! crontab -l | grep "~/runthis.sh \"$1\"\$"; then
                                     # ^^^^^^^^ also check the parameter
    (crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * ~/runthis.sh \"$1\"") | crontab -
  fi                                         #  ^^^^^^^ double quotes
}

cronjobs "$1"
```

Comment: seems like I forgot to pass the $1 into cronjobs. thanks for helping me out! much appreciated 

Comment: btw, do I have to use double quotes on that one? would `cronjobs $1` just work?

Comment: Yes, we should better use double quotes, see my update

Comment: thanks for the update! however, after testing this script throughly, realized that even tho the cronjob gets added correctly, its not running the `./runthis.sh "foo"` every minute. I've tried both with double quotes and without them, still no luck. the `foo` part doesn't take any affect.

when I run the `./runthis.sh foo` from the shell, it works, no problem with that, but it just doesn't work from the crontab.

Comment: Add `exec 9>>"${0}.log"; BASH_XTRACEFD=9; set -x` this line to the beginning of your script, if the interpreter of the script is `/bin/bash`. After 1 or 2 minutes, you can check the file `~/runthis.sh.log` to see what happened.

Comment: I tried that now and checked the log file and it just has the content of `runthis.sh` and it keeps adding it every time the crontab runs. what should I see in here?

Comment: `set -x` will enable debug in your script. You should see all the commands executed, including variables.

Comment: alright, seems like crontab is executing the command perfectly and the script itself is doing its job as well. however, nothing is happening. I guess that's another story tho. thank you for your help so far! much appreciate 